# PHP Convert a text from $_GET to normal readable text

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a search form in my page where a user submits a query. The form is submitted and the search query is submitted in the browser's url. The PHP searches and return the result. E.g. http://example.com/search-results.php?q=ABC+books

The result page has its own independant search form which includes the text box. I use $_GET['q'] to get the text in the input box which displays `ABC books`.

The problem is when I use search queries that contain characters like an apostrophe ('). E.g. when I search Marley's Bar the URL would be -  http://example.com/search-results.php?q= marley%27s+bar The outputted text in the input box displays marley\'s bar I would like to return the value as 'marley's bar' without the slash.

I tried

```
$getSearchQuery = $_GET['q'];
$getSearchQuery = rawurldecode($getSearchQuery);
```

but the output is still the same.

Comment: did you try `html_entity_decode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Friend I think you're looking for this**

**Example #1 A stripslashes() example**

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

**Example #2 Using stripslashes() on an array**

```
<?php
function stripslashes_deep($value)
{
    $value = is_array($value) ?
                array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
}

// Example
$array = array("f\\'oo", "b\\'ar", array("fo\\'o", "b\\'ar"));
$array = stripslashes_deep($array);

// Output
print_r($array);
?>
```

Please have look at [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: That's I must have missed that function. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't apply that willynilly. The slashes are only being added in the first place because of a system configuration option.

Comment: we can use this on displaying data. w.r.t security.